# Regex to get matching line from a text file

Tags: regex

I have the following text in a text file.

```
SREV_OpportunityHandler.OppBeforeUpdate(Trigger.New, Trigger.OldMap);
SREV_OpportunityHandler.OppAfterUpdate(Trigger.New, Trigger.OldMap);
```

The line which I want will always start with `SREV_<SomeChar> Handler.<MethodName>()`
I want to get the just the method   name by regEx. There may be N number of such lines, so in case of above text I need to match the following 2 strings:

```
OppBeforeUpdate
OppAfterUpdate
```

Comment: Using what language?

Comment: @Ketan Mehta: You should also post what you have tried to do. That is why your post is downvoted.

Comment: I have used (?<=SREV_)(.*)(?=)[(] it is able to capture only the first line and it is capturing "OpportunityHandler.OppBeforeUpdate"

Comment: If I use (?<=Handler.)(.*)(?=)[(] I am able to get the method name but only for the first line ... how make it search in multiple line?

Comment: I am trying this on https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

The first capturing group will hold the required method name and should work with all NFA regex engines:

`\bSREV\w+Handler\.(\w+)(?=\()`

Comment: It is capturing only from the first finding... how about multiple lines? By the way I am trying this on https://regex101.com/

Comment: @KetanMehta: Here you are: https://regex101.com/r/zW7gE4/1. You just have to specify `g` option (=global).

Comment: I have the same code on https://regex101.com/r/sI0jX3/1 but still finding the first occurrence only... My doubt is, will it work consistently?

Comment: @KetanMehta: While the regex patterns are the same, I am using the "g" option that means *return all matches*. Even if you use this PCRE-compatible regex that you provided in the post comment (I fixed it a bit) - `(?<=Handler\.)(.*)(?=\()` - you'll only be able to match 1 method occurrence **unless** you specify "g" option. Click `code generator`, and you try the example in your programming language, and you'll see.

Comment: Hi stribizhev, The above expression works fine but when tried to use the same in SFDC it is showing a message as '\w' is illegal character. I tried to replace it with '\\w' then no error but it is not working. Is there any way to replace the \w with alternative?

Comment: I m using '/\bSREV\w+handler\.(\w+)(?=\()/gi'  expression. Basically it has issue with \w and \. and \( characters

Comment: The alternative is '\bSREV_[a-zA-Z0-9]+handler[.]([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?=)' this is working exactly on www.regex101.com and the same is getting compiled in SFDC but no result... may be SFDC does not support or the file content I am reading is different...  Anyways I will try out :)

Comment: Hi, `\w` is equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Also, please check http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/22409, it is written that "^ and $ boundaries [are included] by default around the string".